# Powershell 2 remove single binding iis 7

Tags: iis-7, powershell, binding

I am trying to remove one site binding.  I am using powershell 2 and iis 7.  I am able to remove all bindings with Remove-ItemProperty, and when i use Set-ItemProperty it removes all binding and just adds the new.  I would be great if i could just rename or just remove a single binding without effecting the others.  A sample would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the itemproperty cmdltes (you could, but it's trickier.) There are dedicated cmdlets for this in the WebAdministration module. See:

```
help remove-webbinding -examples
```

-Oisin

Answer (score 0):

I think [xOn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6920/x0n) is correct that you should be using the *higher level* cmdlets but these commands based on the ***-ItemProperty** cmdlets allow you to modify an existing binding. I'm not sure of the syntax to remove one of the bindings though.

```
$bindings = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' -Name Bindings)
$bindings.Collection[0].bindingInformation = '*:80:'
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' -Name Bindings -Value $bindings
```

Read the [PowerShell Snap-in: Making Simple Configuration Changes to Web-Sites and Application Pools](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/434/powershell-snap-in-making-simple-configuration-changes-to-web-sites-and-application-pools/) article to see how to work with the *-ItemProperty commands properly. There is a whole series of articles on [Using Scripts to Automate Management](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/98/using-scripts-to-automate-management/) to manage IIS 7